# A differential inequality with boundary values

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, boundary-value-problem

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable function on $(0,1)$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f''+2f'+f \ge 0$

Then which of the following values cannot be attained by $f$ ?

$(a)\quad \pi$

$(b) \quad e$

$(c) \quad e^{\pi}$

$(d) \quad {\pi}^e$

My first thinking was to take equality with zero .

Then $f(x)=(a+bx)e^{-x}$ whefe $a,b$ are arbitary constants

With the boundary value , we have $a=0=b$ so $f=0$ . So no conclusiions

Again taking the differential equation

$f''+2f'+f=e^{\pi x}$

We have the general solution as

$f(x)=(a+bx)e^{-x}+\frac{e^{\pi x 
} }{(\pi+1)^2}$

With the boundary values

$a=-\frac 1{(\pi+1)^2}$ and $b=\frac{e^{\pi+1}}{(\pi+1)^2}+ 
 \frac 1{(\pi+1)^2} $

But what to conclude from this this?

I am totally confused since I am new to this type of problem.

Please help me solve this question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Even if someone could give a link or references to a related theory , then that would be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=e^xf(x)$. Then $g(0)=g(1)=0$ and $g''(x)=e^x(f''(x)+2f'(x)+f(x))\ge 0$. This means that $g$ is a convex function. Now remember how a secant lies relative to a convex function to conclude that $g(x)\le 0$ and thus also $f(x)\le 0$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @LutzLehman   Loved the idea!! Thanks sir.